# Creating Model Listener on liferay Social Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I have created my custom Model Listener for Social Office Calendar as [this thread](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/3229889) suggests but when trying to [extend my plugin](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/lp-6-1-dgen02-creating-plugins-to-extend-plugins-0) the build fails and the reason is that the target "compile-java" does not exist in the project.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\devel\fishnet\liferay-fishnet-project-6-2\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-plugin-ext.xml:66: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\devel\fishnet\liferay-fishnet-project-6-2\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-plugin-ext.xml:347: The following error occurred while executing this line:
Target "compile-java" does not exist in the project "calendar-new-portlet".
```

Does this have to do with the build-common-plugin-ext.xml or I should have followed another procedure for implementing a custom model listener in social office calendar?

Note: I have extended successfully other social office plugins(chat-portlet, contacts etc.) with the same build file(build-common-plugin-ext.xml) but in those cases I didn't add a custom Java class like now with the model listener.

Comment: Consider adding the platform you're working on to the tag list. The liferay tags might not generate that many views.

Answer (score 0):

Model listeners are not available in an `ext` plugin because `ext`s are designed to directly override portal classes.

To add just a model listener, I suggest using a `hook` plugin by doing the following:

1. Navigate to `/hooks/` in your Plugins SDK.
2. Use the create script to create a new hook (ex. `./create.sh my-test "My Test"`)
3. Then in `/my-test-hook/docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-hook.xml` write:

   ```
   <hook>
       <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
   </hook>
   ```
4. Create `/my-test-hook/docroot/WEB-INF/src/portal.properties`.
5. Now add your model listener:
   `value.object.listener.com.liferay.portal.model.User=com.test.MyListener`

Comment: what I'm trying to do is to add a listener for a model entity of a plugin portlet like social office calendar. So I have to add value.object.listener.com.liferay.calendar.model.Calendar=com.liferay.calendar.model.listeners.CalendarListener in service.properties and not in portal.properties.